# How to set a background image (behind text) with apache poi xwpf

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a docx-template and like to add a background image to the first page.
The image should be behind the text and also be centered horizontally and vertically.

I already tried the following solution from @AmitabhRanjan, but this just adds an image to the bottom of the document:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17849834/23421744

Apache POI Version: 5.2.5

Many thanks in advice.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248276/add-watermark-in-word-document-using-apache-poi/48250236#48250236, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024250/how-can-i-set-the-complete-page-background-for-a-word-page-with-apache-poi/71031876#71031876

Comment: Thank you!
I've tried your solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71024250/how-can-i-set-the-complete-page-background-for-a-word-page-with-apache-poi/71031876#71031876) - it adds the backgroud, but to every page. 
Is it possible to just get it on the first page?

Comment: Regarding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48248276/add-watermark-in-word-document-using-apache-poi/48250236#48250236 : This solution fails with an IndexOutOfBoundsException while initiating xmlobjects.

Comment: "This solution fails... ": Both just tested. Works for me without any problems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"I have a docx-template and like to add a background image to the first page. The image should be behind the text and also be centered horizontally and vertically." sounds like a picture in header of first page. A such can be inserted using current Apache POI  and following code:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.model.XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooterWatermarkPicture {

 static void setWatermarkPictureInParagraph(XWPFParagraph paragraph, String rId, String width, String height) throws Exception {    
  String pictXML = "" 
   + "<w:pict xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" "
   + "xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\">"
   + "<v:shapetype id=\"_x0000_t75\" coordsize=\"21600,21600\" o:spt=\"75\" o:preferrelative=\"t\" path=\"m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe\" filled=\"f\" stroked=\"f\">"
   + "<v:stroke joinstyle=\"miter\"/>"
   + "<v:formulas>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @0 1 0\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"sum 0 0 @1\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @2 1 2\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelWidth\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelHeight\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @0 0 1\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @6 1 2\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelWidth\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @8 21600 0\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelHeight\"/>"
   + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @10 21600 0\"/>"
   + "</v:formulas>"
   + "<v:path o:extrusionok=\"f\" gradientshapeok=\"t\" o:connecttype=\"rect\"/>"
   + "<o:lock v:ext=\"edit\" aspectratio=\"t\"/>"
   + "</v:shapetype>"
   + "<v:shape id=\"WordPictureWatermark3948907\" o:spid=\"_x0000_s2050\" type=\"#_x0000_t75\" "
   + "style=\"position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:" + width + ";height:" + height + ";z-index:-251657216;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin\" "
   + "o:allowincell=\"f\">"
   + "<v:imagedata r:id=\"" + rId + "\" gain=\"19661f\" blacklevel=\"22938f\"/>"
   + "</v:shape>"
   + "</w:pict>"
  ;
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject pictXmlObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(pictXML);
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.getCTR().set(pictXmlObject);
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body of first page:");
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);  

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("The Body of second page:");

  // get or create the default header
  XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
  
  // get or create first paragraph in default header
  paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
  if (paragraph == null) paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  
  // crate a picture reference in header
  InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./logo.png");
  String rId = header.addPictureData(is, Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
  
  // set watermark picture to the paragraph in header
  setWatermarkPictureInParagraph(paragraph, rId, "450pt", "300pt");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordHeaderFooterWatermarkPicture.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Note: Method `setWatermarkPictureInParagraph` uses XML directly since all `XWPFPicture,addPicture` methods only add pictures positioned inline with text. Until now there is not a nataive Apache POI method to insert pictures positioned other than that.